# MySQL Stored Procedure not returning data to C# app if IF / ELSE used in proc?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am calling a MySQL stored proc from a C# app.

Depending on the number of records available, I want to call different sql statements, so I used an if statement.  i.e. if n records exist, then use this statement, else...

For some reason, as soon as use an if statement in the stored proc, although it will work when tested using MySQL, it won't work when calling it from my C# app.  Focus just does not seem to return to the calling proc - the app just hangs on the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); statement.

If I remove the if statement in the stored proc and use one sql select and call it from the C# app, it works fine.

Any idea what is up?

```
C#:
 private List<Record> GetListOfRecordsToProcess(string exchange, string shareCode, DateTime lastProcessedDate, Indicator indicator)
    {
        List<Record> list = new List<Record>();

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Data.cs);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("get_records_to_process1", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_exchange", exchange);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_share_code", shareCode);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_from_date", lastProcessedDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_num_days", (int)indicator);
        conn.Open();

        //Create MySqlDataAdapter object and assign the query and connection to it
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

MySQL:
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_records_to_process1`(
p_exchange varchar(10),
p_share_code varchar(10),
p_from_date date,
p_num_days int)

BEGIN

-- variables
declare data_count int;

-- for debugging
declare counter int;
set counter = 1;

-- for debugging
call log_message_insert (5, concat(counter,' Start'));
set counter = counter + 1;
call log_message_insert (5, concat(counter, ' p_exchange: ', p_exchange, ',    p_share_code: ', p_share_code, ', p_from_date: ', p_from_date, ', p_num_days: ', p_num_days));
set counter = counter + 1;

-- find out if we have enough data to calculate the ema
select count(1) into data_count
  from eod_data_sharenet s1 
 where s1.exchange = p_exchange
   and s1.share_code = p_share_code;

if data_count < p_num_days then

  select *
    from eod_data_sharenet
   where 1 = 2; -- insufficient data, return nothing

else

  select *
from eod_data_sharenet eds
   where eds.exchange = p_exchange
     and eds.share_code = p_share_code
     and eds.trading_date > p_from_date;

end if;

END
```

Proc modified as per Alex suggestion and works:

```
private List<Record> GetListOfRecordsToProcess(string exchange, string shareCode, DateTime lastProcessedDate, Indicator indicator)
    {

        List<Record> list = new List<Record>();

        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(Data.cs);

        using (connection)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("get_records_to_process", connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_exchange", exchange);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_share_code", shareCode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_from_date", lastProcessedDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_num_days", (int)indicator);
            connection.Open();

            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Record newRecord = new Record(Convert.ToDateTime(reader["trading_date"].ToString()),
                                                  reader["exchange"].ToString(),
                                                  reader["share_code"].ToString(),
                                                  Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(reader["close"].ToString())));

                    list.Add(newRecord);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        connection.Close();

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`, this won't return result, please use [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyy0sz6b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Indeed.  Once again StackOverflow saves me from my schoolboy mistakes. Thanks Alex. Modified proc that I used to test is appended above.

Answer (score 0):

Solution as suggested by Alex:

```
private List<Record> GetListOfRecordsToProcess(string exchange, string shareCode, DateTime lastProcessedDate, Indicator indicator)
    {

        List<Record> list = new List<Record>();

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Data.cs))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("get_records_to_process", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_exchange", exchange);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_share_code", shareCode);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_from_date", lastProcessedDate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_num_days", (int)indicator);
                conn.Open();

                using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Record newRecord = new Record(Convert.ToDateTime(reader["trading_date"].ToString()),
                                                          reader["exchange"].ToString(),
                                                          reader["share_code"].ToString(),
                                                          Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(reader["close"].ToString())));

                            list.Add(newRecord);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```